# Merge multiple cookies into one

Tags: servlets, cookies, servlet-filters

In our application, we use cookies to set the authenticated SAML tokens and other information.
This approach works for almost all scenarios.

But if the customers have very lengthy private keys and certificates, the SAML tokens generated are going beyond the size a cookie can handle and hence the cookie is dropping the values as it exceeds 4K limit.

The approach we thought was to break the cookie into multiple cookies so that one will hole SAML token, other cookies will hold user information and etc etc.
Doing this is not a big deal as we just have to create multiple cookies.

But the twist in tale is here, our application uses a framework which expects cookie with specific name and all values set in it.
As we thought of breaking the values into multiple cookies, the further requests fail.

I thought of having a filter which will intercept all requests and merge the multiple cookie values into one and feed it to the framework as it expects.

- Is that a right approach
- If so are there any utilities which will merge cookies into one and set it back to request so that framework can continue processing the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed decorate/wrap `HttpServletRequest#getCookies()` with a custom implementation which returns an array with the desired cookies. You can do this with help of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

Basically, it should look like this in the filter:

```
chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
    @Override
    public Cookie[] getCookies() {
        Cookie[] originalCookies = super.getCookies();

        // Loop, check, merge, create new Cookie[].
        // ...

        return newCookies;
    }
}, response);
```

You can even do the same for `HttpServletResponse#addCookie()` so that cookies with lengthy values will be automagically captured and split. You can do this with help of `HttpServletResponseWrapper` the same way.